# What shading technique/effect was used in this calligraphy?

Tags: style-identification, photography, calligraphy

Do you know what technique was used in this calligraphy? I would like to use Illustrator CS6 to achieve this look. 
The effect looks like glow in the dark.

[image: Image of Calligraphy]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Scott is exactly right](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/51089/408). This is a photograph and there was no editing done to it to make it look the way it looks -- this is straight out of the camera.

When a camera takes a picture it opens its shutter. During the time the shutter is open it absorbs light. The longer you leave the shutter open, the more light comes in.

In this particular photo the shutter was left open for a considerable amount of time.

A person, or multiple persons with lights then "painted" using the lights.
These lights are handheld and can be flashlights, phones, glowsticks, etc.

The lines where creating by moving the light source around. This creates a streak of light. Stopping a line merely means turning off the light.

You can change the thickness of the light by tilting the light source so that it shines at the camera from a different angle. (Think about looking at your monitor straight on versus looking at it from the side, the shape of the light is different)

Below is another example of the same concept (one of my own pictures)
[image]

It was made using a flashlight.

There is no software involved, it's 100% photography.

Another way to think about this is as a motion blur, where when you move the camera while taking the picture, the whole picture is blurry. In this case you are moving something else while the camera stays still and it paints the blur onto the picture. The results of the picture you posted and the one I linked to are simply that of a "light blur" where a source of light covers distance during the exposure.

The shape of the blur is of course controlled by the person with the lights, enabling them to paint words, pictures, or abstract shapes.

Another thing to notice is that you'll usually see these "light paintings" take place in a dark picture (during night time, indoors) because taking them during the daytime would introduce too much light from the sun and ruin the picture.

*To address Gin-San's comment:*

The reason you don't see the person is because they are constantly moving in the picture, much in the same way the light is.  The difference is that a person doesn't give off light, so they aren't captured as fast as the light source is.
The longer the shutter is open, the easier it is to make a person disappear.

Here is an example photograph where you can see how a person's motion influences a long exposure:

[image]
[Source - Martin Roemers](http://www.martinroemers.com/work.php?serie_dir=01Metropolis)

You'll notice how people who are standing still are captured more clearly than those that are in motion. Now imagine this shot were taken at night and the people were moving much faster -- they'd essentially become invisible.

Comment: ok, thanks. In that case, it's really cool that you can achieve a light effect with a camera

Comment: Yes, I've added some additional details, but it's really straightforward if you understand the way cameras work with light. If you have a camera of your own that can control shutter speed this effect is very easy to reproduce.

Comment: Why is there no person to be seen in your picture? If you walked through the scene with a flashlight, wouldn't there be a blurred shape of you in the photo as well?

Comment: @Gin-San. Great question -- I've edited my answer to explain why you don't see the person in the photograph.

Comment: I have seen many early 19th century photos of landmark buildings on nearly abandoned streets, but they were in fact taken during the day in extremely busy market areas. If you look carefully at the originals you often can see the occasional "ghost wagon wheel" or foot. The long exposures and slow film chemicals are not fast enough to capture moving figures.

Comment: @Johannes +1, that's really cool!

Answer (score 8):

This is a **photograph**.

By leaving a camera shutter open, sitting on a tripod, it's a common effect to use light to create interesting shapes with the long exposure time. A person moved around with a light and the camera picked up the light.

There is  *nothing* in that image that is not part of the original photograph.

it's a known photography effect ------> [look here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1096&bih=1367&q=light+photographs&oq=light+photographs&gs_l=img.3..0i10l10.1250.3500.0.3669.17.11.0.3.3.0.218.1182.0j6j2.8.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..6.11.1189.QpqsUnC8EME#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=light+photography&spell=1)

There's no software used.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I'm asking about the calligraphy effect.

Comment: What calligraphy?? there's no type in that photo. It's all light. Calligraphy is type.

Comment: The blue and yellow letter design

Comment: The "effect" was made using a light, the rotation of said light influences the shape of the "calligraphy" there is no letter design in the photo.

Comment: Again.. it's someone moving a light around... it's not type. Chances are the fact that the light formed shapes which resemble letters could be pure happenstance.

Comment: the calligraphy is in Arabic letters.

Comment: Then they turn on/off the light during the picture to form the shapes. It's still 100% light and 100% photograph.

Comment: The designer used a text effect either in Illustrator or photoshop. I want to know how the designer achieved the look.

Comment: No.. there's no software there. It's again.. 100% photograph. Why do you think software was used?

Comment: I don't understand how you could think that's 100% natural light?? It is a illustrator/photoshop effect

Comment: If that's true could you provide proof that they designer used software for this?

Comment: It's not natural light. It's light from a flashlight or phone or other artificial light source.

Comment: [LOOK HERE](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1096&bih=1367&q=light+photographs&oq=light+photographs&gs_l=img.3..0i10l10.1250.3500.0.3669.17.11.0.3.3.0.218.1182.0j6j2.8.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..6.11.1189.QpqsUnC8EME#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=light+photography&spell=1) it is a photo technique and not a software technique.

Comment: lol it is an Arabic Calligraphy not English letters. That's what I want to know, the effect that was used.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's English, Arabic, a horse, or anything else painted with light, they are all made the same way *with light*.

Comment: @Scott, I agree with you in that it's all light, but would beg to differ on the 'Calligraphy is type' statement. 

In my understanding, type is abstracted, mechanic calligraphy, but NOT calligraphy. Calligraphy is made by hand (or arms and flashlight, as in the picture), so it's 'artisanal'; Type takes a model and reproduces it mechanically (or digitally), as in a font.

Answer (score 2):

Though other answers are correct in describing light painting, there is a software/hardware combination available to predefine an image and then recreate using the light painting method. The product is called [Pixel Stick](http://www.thepixelstick.com/)

This product allows you to recreate specific images within a light painting by connecting the device to a computer and pre-defining the images to be created--as opposed to haplessly waiving a light around and hoping for the best.

In my opinion, this takes the "light painting" experimentation and art out of the medium, but the results are pretty cool.

Last January, [Wired Magazine](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2014/02/play/rainbow-dash) did a pretty cool article on the then active [kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bitbangerlabs/pixelstick-light-painting-evolved) which raised over 1/2 a million bucks to bring the project to life.

Here is another [link to a great review](http://www.lightingrumours.com/pixelstick-review-6838#.VSwBlJOOXvM) on the entire process...posted just a few days ago (March 9th, 2015).

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be looked as light painting as suggested by most users. But in my point of view, it could be a mix (Digital Painting with some light painting).

I have some experience in photography, digital painting and light painting as well. A pure light painting to get the desired results would be extremely difficult and involves a heck of trial and error. While in digital paintings, accuracy is achieved with much precision.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to replicate the effect with software such as [Amberlight](http://www.escapemotions.com/products/amberlight/index.php) or [Flame Painter](http://www.escapemotions.com/products/flamepainter/)